# Nag Hammadi "The Secret Book of James". Chilling Quote (In body paragraph). What do you guys think?

Tags: jesus, james, commandments-of-jesus

The last word:

"Nevertheless, you, through faith and knowledge have received life. So disregard rejection when you hear it, and when you hear about the promise, be joyful all the more.

I tell you the truth, whoever will receive life and believe in the kingdom will never leave it, not even if the father wants to banish him"

My commentary:
If this is the truth where is the "Rock" Or true vine we are holding onto if without the father we can still hold onto the kingdom. If the father were to want to banish us, then through his word all should follow and we would be banished. IMO this has dangerous consequences believing in this line because it can lead to solipsism, and anyone who tries to rise higher than god usually is punished (if not always). So how is this a reasonable line? If it's true then we would have to be greater than the father and have more power. The only thing I can say is that this is an untrue line.

Comment: Is this even a Biblical question?

Answer (score 2):

The quote from the "Secret Book of James" is unbiblical and misleading.  Read the Bible primarily and compare everything to Scripture.

No one who is in the Kingdom is desired, by the Father, to be expelled.

We are not "holding onto" the true vine.  We are told to remain in Christ (the true vine) and we will bear fruit.  This remaining is not a grabbing but a vital connection.  The branch does not grab the vine...it grows out from it.  Vitality from the vine (the vine's vitality) flows into the branch and the branch can only draw from the vine.  The branch is entirely dependent on the vitality of the vine.

There is no taking part of this process against the Father's will because the process is the Father's will.  It is the Father's will for us to bear much fruit and abiding in the vine (not grabbing or grasping) is the process the Father has willed.